# aws-vault in Windows: Failed to get credentials for profile: operation error STS: GetSessionToken

Tags: aws-vault

Setup aws-vault.exe v.7.2.0 on new windows 11 pc.

Getting error on connection:
Failed to get credentials for [profile]: operation error STS: GetSessionToken, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: [id number], api error AccessDenied: MultiFactorAuthentication failed, unable to validate MFA code.  Please verify your MFA serial number is valid and associated with this user.

```
    Config contents:
    [profile test]
    output=json
    region=us-east-1
    credential_process = C:\test\aws-vault.exe exec test --json
    mfa_serial=arn:aws:iam::[account code]:mfa/[username]
```

The expectation is that will prompt for MFA code from authenticator app.

copied config file from previous pc. tried older versions of vault. confirmed creds stored in vault (removed and added twice).

Can't figure out what is wrong here.